# WPF Triggers - Pain Points

Tags: wpf, triggers, skinning

I have a very big control, which in-turn contains lots of small controls hosted in it. Previously, we were applying themes using VisualTree iteration. We planned to replace the logic with Triggers. Now, when we apply any theme it takes much time than the previous implementation. [For example, previously it took around 100ms now it varies from 1-2s]

My question is this. 
Is there some thing we should avoid while using Triggers in WPF? 
or Using Triggers for such a big project for applying themes is a bad idea?